# How does OpenLayers 3 handle coordinates?

Tags: openlayers, coordinate-system, proj

**Ol3** always uses the **flatCoordinates** because obviously it needs 2d-coordinates as the screen is only 2-dimensional. But how does **OL3** calculate the flat representation?

For example if my view’s projection was **EPSG:25832** (UTM Zone 32) it could calculate the transversal Mercator Projection (with help from **proj4.js**) to obtain the flat coordinates. How is this processed with, for example, **EPSG:4326** (WGS84), which is using geographical coordinates? Which projection does **OL3** apply here?

Comment: More info on `flatCoordinates:` https://stackoverflow.com/q/67225734/9778755